# What Specs are Important in Choosing a Similar Stepper Motor?

Tags: stepper-motor

I am building a simple [DIWire Bender](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIWire-Bender/).  Included in their Google Code Site materials list is the [OrientalMotor 2 Phase Stepper Motor](http://catalog.orientalmotor.com/item/stepping-motors/pk-series-stepping-motors/pk264a2a-sg10?&amp%3Bseo=110), which will be responsible for feeding and bending the wire.  Each motor is priced around $200, and in total they exceed my budget.  I am searching for similar but less expensive solutions below 100 bucks.

**Which variables in this spec list would be critical in choosing a similar motor?**

> Motor Type :  2-Phase
>
> Holding Torque : 368 oz-in
>
> Shaft/Gear Type   : Spur Gear
>
> Gear Ratio (X:1) : 10 :1
>
> Shaft : Single
>
> Type : Geared
>
> Output Step Angle : 0.18 °
>
> Connection Type   : Bipolar (Series) / Unipolar
>
> Current per Phase (A/phase)   : 1.4 [Bipolar (Series)] / 2 [Unipolar]
>
> Voltage (VDC) : 3.9 [Bipolar (Series)] /2.8 [Unipolar]
>
> Resistance (Ω/phase) : 2.8 [Bipolar (Series)] / 1.4 [Unipolar]
>
> Shaft Runout      0.05 mm (0.002 in.) T.I.R.
>
> Concentricity     0.075 mm (0.003 in.) T.I.R.
>
> Perpendicularity      0.075 mm (0.003 in.) T.I.R.
>
> Radial Play       0.025 mm (0.001 in.) maximum of 5 N (1.12 lb.)
>
> Axial Play        0.075 mm (0.003 in.) maximum of 10 N (2.2 lb.)

Comment: It depends. The circuit you use to drive the motor might or might not be able to drive others. And the design of the rest of the system may mean that some specs are flexible and others are not. But driver circuit aside, you probably just want a motor with the same or higher torque, and step angle of the same or less.

Comment: @Jodes :  Thanks for the comment -  my research so far has come up with a similar solution.